# Optimizing getting absolute rectangle of Widget?

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm profiling my game and it seems I spend a good amount of time here:

```
    const Rectangle Widget::getAbsoluteRectangle() const
0.01s       {
            Point absLocation;

0.00s           absLocation = getLocation();

            if(!getParent())
            {
                return Rectangle(absLocation.getX(),absLocation.getY(),
                    getSize().getWidth(),getSize().getHeight());
            }

            const Widget* parent = this;
            int eX = 0;
            int eY = 0;

            while(parent->getParent() != NULL)
            {
0.02s               parent = parent->getParent();

0.01s               eX = parent->getMargin(SIDE_LEFT);
0.04s               eY = parent->getMargin(SIDE_TOP);

0.03s               absLocation.setX(absLocation.getX() + parent->getLocation().getX() + eX);
0.04s               absLocation.setY(absLocation.getY() + parent->getLocation().getY() + eY);
            }

0.02s           return Rectangle(absLocation,getSize());
0.01s       }
```

I thought of maybe caching the result of this and invalidating it when one of its parents move or resize but first I'd like to know if there are any obvious optimizations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're re-computing the parent's position every time. What you need to do is a recursive algorithm to compute them all at once. For example:

```
class Widget {
public:
    Rectangle AbsolutePosition;
    Rectangle RelativePosition;
    std::vector<Widget*> children;

    void ComputePositions(Rectangle ParentPosition) {
        ComputeAbsoluteFromParentAndRelative(ParentPosition);
        std::for_each(children.begin(), children.end(), [&](Widget* child) {
            child->ComputePositions(AbsolutePosition);
        });
    }
};
```

Using this method, each widget has it's position computed only and exactly once, and the current absolute location is already cached. In addition, the loop can be parallelized if necessary trivially, since each iteration is independent. Finally, you can control easily the level at which `ComputePositions` is called, instead of having to call it at the root every time.